# making a pandas + tkinter interface, return string value from a sample()

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

trying to make a `tkinter` interface with pandas + big database, how to return only the string relative to the selected column with a 'sample'

in the 'generateHand' function I generate a random line from my df, after that I take the 'Hand' column of this result and return to the value of the `tkinter` label, but it is coming as an object and not just the string I need

```py
df = pd.read_csv(f'reports/report_IP_Full.csv')

def generateHand():
    hand = df.sample()['Hand']
    return hand

def handleButtton():
    hand = generateHand()
    lbl['text'] = hand

btn = Button(root, text='button', command=handleButtton)
btn.grid()
```

I also tried a version with return in .str

```py
def generateHand():
    sample = df.sample()
    return sample['Hand'].str
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you were supposed to use `df.sample()["Hand"]`? Try printing it out. Is it what you expect?

Comment: no, I expect Ks8s for example, but return is a dataframe

Comment: Can I ask the question why you would like to use tkinter? I'D recommend to use something like streamlit, which is easier to handle and produces outcomes in pretty fast time, since extremely user friendly

Comment: @SMS I just trying something and want a performatic ones, but ty for recomendation

Comment: try str(list(df.sample()["Hand"])[0]). This will give you the item as string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with

```py
def generateHand():
    sample = df.sample()
    return sample['Hand'].item()
```